# Name of a statistical dispersion searched

Tags: terminology, standard-deviation

Suppose I have a data set $ x=\{x_1,\dots, x_n\} $. Then does the following statistical dispersion exist?

$$ \frac 1 n \sum_{i,j\in n} |x_i-x_j| $$

If not, why? It is independent of mean values, sounds interesting. But it grows exponentially in computational effort.

I played around with it a bit and it behaves similar to the geometric mean with its GSD, but of course looks much simpler than the GSD

Comment: Title and body ask different questions.

Answer (score 2):

The statistic
$$U_n=\binom{n}{2}^{-1}\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}\vert X_i-X_j\vert$$

is known as the absolute mean difference  or [Gini’s mean difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_difference). This is a [U-statistic](https://pages.stat.wisc.edu/%7Edoksum/STAT709/n709-33.pdf) of order 2 for the kernel $h(x_1,x_2) = \vert x_1 - x_2\vert.$

Comment: thank you very much, currently reading it!